# php redirect issue after email sent

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am getting the old header problem just cant get it to redirect how do I fix it?

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
  $content = '<html><body>';
  $content .= 'Email Address: '.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
  $content .= 'Enquiry Type: '.$_POST['enquiry'].'<br />';
  $content .= 'Message: '.$_POST['message'].'<br />';
  $content .= 'Telephone Number: '.$_POST['telephone'].'<br />';
  $content .= 'Preferred Contact Method:" '.$_POST['contact-method'] ;
  $content .= '</body></html>';
  $to = 'myemail*email.com';

$subject = 'Website Contact Form ';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
header('Location:form-submitted.php');
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: Be sure you don't have any blank lines before the oening `<?php` tag.

Comment: there must be *something* printing content before this code is executed. Is this all the code that appears at the top of the page you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that header is already been sent. 
Please try this

echo `"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=form-submitted.php\">";`

Answer (score 0):

Use exit(); After header function.

```
header('Location:form-submitted.php');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an **invalid email-id**

```
$to = 'myemail*email.com';
```

**Should be**

```
$to = 'myemail@email.com';// @ in place of *
```

So, `mail` will `return false` in above case.

Answer (score 0):

put this line below:

```
 ob_start();
```

at the beginning of executed PHP file works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put this code at the top of your page
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

Your code.....

```
//Put this code at the bottom of your page
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JS

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers)) {   
?>
<script>window.location.replace("http://your url/");</script>
<?php 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the explanation: Remove everything that might me printing to the website that is **before** the `header("Location: site.php")`. This is because http headers is always at the top of an request or response. This means that if you echo or print anything to the response before the header is set results in something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 18 Oct 2012 10:36:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)
Content-Length: 230
<p>this tag should not be here</p>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<p>` element as you can see above, may have been printed out with php, and have now corrupted the http response. Anything you want to set with the `header();` function will be throwing errors.

I hope this helped :)